# How to Create Services in Windows Mobile 6

Tags: windows-mobile, service, wms

Hello Everyone
Do you know how to run services in Windows Mobile Application.
So it can running on background and i can handle the all mobile events through that Services.

Please give me comment or give example link.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Services in CE are just like stream interface drivers from an entry point perspective.  [MDSN documents what you need here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee499183.aspx).

The primary difference is the registry entries used to tell the OS how to load it.  You want it loaded by services.exe, not device.exe, so you simply use the [proper registry entries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee500226.aspx) (or manually load it with a call to [RegisterService](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa450871.aspx))

Comment: Thanks for you answer. Can you give me any example code so i can check it out where to change registry value and where i need to do manually entry.